# How to avoid two ForeignKeys in django model if one of them will be NULL in every case

Tags: sql, django

**The prologue:**

I've got models called:

- Supervisor
- Salesman
- Car
- Motorcycle
- Product (the abstract model for Car and Motorcycle)

A salesman and a supervisor can sell cars. A supervisor also controlls work of two or more salesmen.

**What do I do:**
I want to create the fittest model to that task.

**The problem:**
The problem is that a supervisor can controll salesmen and sell products. I thought to create an abstract model called `'Staff'` which will be share fields between `Salesman` and `Supervisor` and `Product` will have `ForeignKey` to `Staff`. But I can't make `ForeignKey` to an abstract model.
I don't want have `Product` as a table with whether a salesman field or a supervisor field is empty. And I don't want to use generic `ForeignKey` because it's to complex.

**My best guess**: Add John Smith, for example, as a supervisor and a salesman. In this case John Smith salesman has ForeignKey to John Smith a supervisor. But I think there are the best solution.

**The simplest but bad decision.**

```
class Product(models.Model):
  company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name = 'Car company');
  price = models.IntegerField()
  horse_power = models.IntegerField()
  salesman = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, null=True)
  supervisor = models.ForeignKey(Supervisor, null=True)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Car(Product):
  number_of_doors = models.IntegerField()
  is_conditioner = models.NullBooleanField()

class Supervisor(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Salesman(models.Model):
  name = models.ChartField(max_length=100)
  supervisor = models.ForeignKey(Supervisor)
```

My question is what is the best way to rewrite model structure to avoid two ForeignKeys if one of them will be NULL in every case and avoid `ForeignKey` to abstract model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple solution would be to combine `Supervisor` and `Salesman` into 1 model. You could simply call this `Staff` and create a field called `is_supervisor` which would differentiate supervisors from regular salesmen.

To do this, you would set up your model something like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, null=True)
  # other stuff

class Staff(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  supervisor = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
  is_supervisor = models.BooleanField()
```